# Pattern/Matcher not working with line break

Tags: java, regex

I have written a program using Pattern and Matcher in Java to produce a string in between a group of characters. My code is currently:

```
    String trying = "75px;"; 
    Pattern tryingPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<="+Pattern.quote(trying)+").*?(?=center)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher tryingMatcher = tryingPattern.matcher(pageContentString); 

       while (tryingMatcher.find()) {
           docketFile.write(tryingMatcher.group().toString());
    }
```

I am attempting to obtain the information between the "75px;" and and the word "center".
The issue is that any time a sequence comes up as shown below with the information on several lines, it is not recognizing the pattern even though the beginning and ending string exist. I am not sure based off my code why information including line breaks will not allow the pattern to be recognized.

Sample data below.

```
 <td align=*left* valign=*top* style=*width:75px;*>03/04/2013</td><td align=*left* valign=*top*>D6</td><td align=*left* valign=*top*>SR</td><td align=*left*>SUMS AMENDED COMPLNT(20967973) SENT BY CERTIFIED MAIL.
    TO:
    CUYAHOGA CLERK OF COURTS
    1200 ONTARIO CT
    CLEVELAND, OH 44113-0000
    </td><td align=*center*><a href=*DisplayImageList.aspx?q=03WzlSkU6oMVIiKW14aCZBTEV4FirUMU0*><img src=*images/ImageSheet.png* alt=** /></a></td>
            </tr><tr style=*background-color:Gainsboro;*>
```

Comment: you could add the token for dot matches line breaks.  Maybe something like Pattern.DOTALL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pattern.MULTILINE` affects the behavior of `^` and `$` (to match the beginning and the end of the line), which you don't use at all in your pattern.

For your use case, use `DOTALL` as you want all the content to be treated in the single line.

This will work!

```
String trying = "75px;"; 
Pattern tryingPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<="+Pattern.quote(trying)+").*?(?=center)", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = tryingPattern.matcher(str);
// check all instances
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: Updated with multiline and it still will not find the matches

Comment: Multiline has to do with the behavior of ^$  I don't think that's what he needs.

Comment: @instanceOfObject Awesome, works great. One Question, if I am writing that multiline code to a file, is there any way to write it out all on one line instead of each individual like as it is in the source code?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding Pattern.DOTALL.

Another option to capture that text would be to use a capturing group:

```
75px(.*)center
```